# unknown field 'nopage' specified in initializer in linux 3.6

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel, mmap

I'm reading the `linux device driver` book and i want to implement the mmap file operation, but i have a problem with the nopage function defined in the old kernel (v2.4) as a field of vm_operations_struct:

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/mm.h?v=2.4.37#L134

It seems that this field is vanished in the 3.6 version (which i'm using):

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/mm.h?v=3.6#L205

can someone say to me how i'm supposed to implement this method?

Comment: As of 2.6.26 nopage has been removed and fault should be used instead. I'll see if I can find a decent tutorial quickly, but I don't have much time to look into it this morning. This changelog mentions it: http://lwn.net/Articles/2.6-kernel-api/

Comment: thank you, i have find it by my self

Comment: @Katie It would be great if you made that an answer, citing the relevant changes, and maybe an example, so that Luca may accept it.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I just looked back into this, but I'm not confident I would get everything about the switch right - I've written mmap handlers with fault() but don't have experience with nopage(). I can find examples of diffs from the kernel where the switch was made, but I can't make extensive use of the code here because I think the GPL would conflict with SO's CC-A-SA licensing.